# ffmpeg add logo and photo and subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello i need add logo and photo and subtitles to a video.

I have this code

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:08 -i "video.mp4" -i photo.jpg -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=2700:1850,subtitles=sub.ass:force_style='WrapStyle=0" -an -vcodec libx264 -shortest -r 25 -crf 17 -aspect 16/9 output.mp4
```

i don't know how to add other filter to scale 50% and center the photo

this is the code to add scaled photo to a video

```
ffmpeg -t 8 -i "video" -i "photo.jpg" -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/2[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -vcodec libx264 -shortest -r 25 -crf 17 -aspect 16/9 "output.mp4"
```

i need to combine both. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -t 8 -i video.mp4 -i photo.jpg -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/2[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto[bg];[bg][2]overlay,subtitles=sub.ass:force_style='WrapStyle=0,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -shortest -r 25 -crf 17 -aspect 16/9 output.mp4
```

Comment: I'm sorry but in your command the logo doesn't appear .

Comment: @fedep11 It's because I simply copied your overlay values (2700:1850) which are too big for anything smaller than 4K. Answer updated. Try again.

Comment: ok thanks that's fine, i manage to scale the logo according the video size, thanks